# How to append an array of json into a json file using jq?

Tags: arrays, json, bash, jq

I have an array of json objects in a file (full_meta.json).

**full_meta.json:**

> `[{"product_id":"xxx","name":"yyy","qty":111},{"product_id":"881","name":"aaa","qty":200}]`

I want to filter a subset of this, modify it and append it to a file (sub_meta.json).
sub_meta:json would contain an empty array to start with. I need to keep appending such values to fill it up
**sub_meta.json:**

> `[]`

I am using the following commands to:
1.Filter and modify id

```
  d=$(jq '[.[] | select(.product_id == "881")] | map(.product_id ="881-new")' full_meta.json)
```

2.Append it to another file

```
  jq --argjson tmp "$d" '.+=$tmp' sub_meta.json
```

I got the following error:

```
parse error: Invalid numeric literal at line 1, column 6
```

What is the best way to achieve this using bash scripting?

Comment: Please edit your question and add your desired output (no description).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Supposing you only want the modified item to be added to the array in `sub_meta.json`: You can load `full_meta.json` as a variable, modify it as you see fit, read `sub_meta.json` as input, append the modification to it, write the result into a temporary file, and if all was successful, replace the old `sub_meta.json` file with the new (temporary) output file.

```bash
jq --argfile f full_meta.json \
  '. + [$f[] | select(.product_id == "881") | .product_id = "881-new"]' \
  sub_meta.json > sub_meta.tmp && mv sub_meta.tmp sub_meta.json
```

Comment: If you have many items to add, it might be more efficient to first just collect all items as a stream (not as an array), which enables you to just append to the output file on shell level (`>>`), and as a single final operation, convert the stream to an array. For example, starting out with an empty (or nonexistent) `sub_meta_stream.json` file, i.e. no empty array in it: Append to the stream as many times as needed with `jq '.[] | select(.product_id == "881") | .product_id = "881-new"' full_meta.json >> sub_meta_stream.json`, then finalize with `jq -s . sub_meta_stream.json > sub_meta.json`.